# Play Framework Search Bar

Tags: scala, model-view-controller, playframework

I'm trying to make a search bar with only one variable - the search input. I'm sure there's a fairly simple way to do this, but everything that I've found about getting input from the DOM (the views file) has been about using a `Form` and getting multiple variables. Is there a simpler way to do this if it's just a single variable?

I have a function in my Applications

```
 def singleElement = Action { implicit request =>
    val databaseSupport = new InteractWithDatabase(comm, db)
    val put = Future {
      while (true) {
        val data = databaseSupport.getFromDatabase()
        if (data.nonEmpty) {
          comm.communicator ! data.head
        }
      }
    }

    Ok(views.html.singleElement)
  }
```

I want to take some input from the user on the page `singleElement` and pass it into `getFromDatabase` which calls a  MySQL query. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use restful and do something like this

## routs file

GET     /content/search/:search                           controllers.ContentController.search(search:String)

and in controller:

public Result search(String saerch) {}

Comment: Would you mind explaining what that long URI and function call are doing? How exactly is this mapping to an HTML file in my Views?

Comment: Just add search param to your URl insted :search for example  localhost:9000/content/search/test123 and thats it you will get in search controller parameter named search type String

Comment: In my localhost:9000/ page, I have a search bar. How do I pass that to localhost:9000/content/search/ without the use of a form? How does it get submitted and passed in order to be pulled using the Get Request?

Comment: first you don't need to use this path  localhost:9000/content/search/  this is my example second you can use ajax call  function search(search) {

  $.ajax({
           url: '/search/+'search,
            type: 'GET',
            async: true,
            success: function(data) { 
               alert("result: "+data);
            },
            error:function(data){
               alert("error: "+data);
            } 
        }); 
 }